# CSS data-content attribute escapes backslashes

Tags: html, css, attributes, attr, backslash

So, I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul>
<li data-content="\ec00"></li>
<li data-content="\ec01"></li>
</ul>
```

When using the data-content attribute in CSS to read the content:

```
li:before { content: attr(data-content) }
```

It shows ec00 and ec01 instead of those with backslashes.

Any ideas how I could go about this?

The idea behind is for a colorpicker for a huge amounts of icons.

Thanks in advance,
Dorian

Comment: What about escaping the slash as well, ie "\\ec00"?

Comment: Did try that, outputs as it is, \\ec00

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are using a character encoding that is not parsed properly in HTML. Remember that the CSS accesses the `data-` attributes as plaintext, and since HTML is does not parse hexadecimal characters, `\ec00` is not parsed as it is supposed to be compared to when it is used as-is in a CSS file.

What you could do is:

- Use the character itself, i.e. '�' in the `data-` attribute
- Use a numeric (decimal) equivalent, that will be parsed by the browser: `&#60416;` (because `ec00` in hexadecimal is `60416` in decimals, and `\ec00` is used to force parsing in CSS while `&#...;` is used to indicate a decimal entity in HTML)

An example would be the copyright symbol:

- Decimal: `169`. In HTML, you will use `&#169;`
- Hexadecimal: `00A9`. In CSS, you will use `\00A9` while in JS you will use `\u00A9`

And here is a proof-of-concept demo:

```css
li:before { content: attr(data-content); margin-right: 1em; }
```

```html
<ul>
<li data-content="&#169;">Using <code>&#169;</code>, parsed by HTML engine.</li>
<li data-content="\u00A9">Using <code>\u00A9</code>, will not be parsed by HTML engine.</li>
  <li data-content="\00A9">Using <code>\00A9</code>, will not be parsed by HTML engine.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Terry, Thanks a lot for your detailed comment, things really make sense now! :) Cheers!